# On spectrum of periodic boundary value problem

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider the following boundary value problem on the infinite strip $(-\infty,\infty)\times[0,1]$ w/periodic conductivity $\gamma(x,y)=\gamma(x+2\pi,y)>0$:
$$\begin{cases}
\operatorname{div}(\gamma\nabla u)=(\gamma u_x)_x+(\gamma u_y)_y=0,\\
u(x+2\pi,y)=\mu u(x,y),\\
u(x,1)=0,\\
u(x,0)=0 \mbox{ or } u_y(x,0)=0.
\end{cases}$$
 Let's denote the set of possible values of the eigenvalue parameter $\mu$, for which the system has a solution $\mu_\gamma$. Does there exist a conductivity $\alpha(y)$ on the strip, depending only on $y$, such that 
 $$\mu_\gamma=\mu_\alpha?$$
 The answer is "yes" for the finite-difference version of the problem, but the proof, that I've got doesn't apply to the continuous case...

Comment: I don't get what is $\sigma_\mu(\gamma)$ ?

Comment: The set of values $\mu$ for which the system has a solution is denoted $\sigma_\mu(\gamma)$...

Comment: changed/improved notation...