# Isospectral transformation of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory, invariance

Is there a transformation of coefficients of differential operators w/periodic coefficients on the real line $a_n(x+2\pi)=a_n(x)$, that preserves the eigenvalues of their monodromy matrices?
$$Df(x)=\sum_n a_n(x)f^{(n)}(x)=0,$$ $$M_D:(f^{(n)}(0))\rightarrow (f^{(n)}(2\pi)).$$
 In particular to constant coefficients? 
 Is this a part of Floquet theory?

Comment: This is a semi-discrete version of the followin question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771950/on-spectrum-of-periodic-boundary-value-problem